# How to make ListView resizable?

Tags: java, android, listview

Picture 1

[image]

Picture 2

[image]

How to make **ListView** resizable?

This **ListView** is OK.
OK ListView 1 Picture

[image]

OK ListView 2 Picture

[image]

I have tried all the layouts. That doesn't help.

I have a fragment container:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/yellow"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/fragmentsContainer"/>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/menu"
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigation"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

OK Layout is Search Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/yellow"
    android:id="@+id/searchAndListViewContainer"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorOfSearchView" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/downloadedMusicListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

unadabtable Layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/darkGreen">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/musicListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

As you see Java Code will change Fragments container's inner content.
Two fragments are almost identical. 
What's the problem?

Comment: layout_weight="1" // is the problem.

Comment: make just header - frame layout - footer inside linear layout and see the difference

Comment: @Radhey removing weight = 1 doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lv"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/tv_footer"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_header" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_footer"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="#ff0000"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Footer" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_header"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="#00ff00"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:text="Header" />        

   </RelativeLayout>
```

you can do that in multiple ways. here you can set your own view as header and footer.